# SpringMVCにて、ViewがNot foundになってしまう

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Springフレームワークを使って、WEBアプリケーション(といってもHello worldですが)を作成しています。

コントローラー抜きでindex.jspを参照することはできるんですが、
コントローラーを実装したところ、Viewが見つからないという旨のエラーが発生し、ブラウザ側では404エラーが発生してしまいます。

大したプログラムではありませんので、そのまま添付します。

src/main/java/{package}/ActionController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ActionController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello() {
        return "showMessage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String top() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

struts-config.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

web.xml(一部)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

以下、ローカルデバッグ時のログです。

```
22:41:42.448 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/contextpath/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp]
22:41:42.448 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp
22:41:42.448 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp]
22:41:42.449 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/contextpath/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
22:41:42.449 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
22:41:42.449 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

上記ログを見る限り、間違いなくコンテキストパスはあっており、
Eclipseの仕様で表示される、”デプロイ済みリソース”を確認する限り、実際に
WEB-INF/view/index.jspおよびshowMessage.jspは存在していました。
ブレークポイントでコントローラーの処理が走ったか否かも確認しましたが、
リクエストは受理されているようでした。

なぜjspが見つからないのでしょうか。
ご指南おねがいいたします。

Answer (score 2):

次のように書き込んでおられるので、確実な回答ではないかもしれません。

> ブレークポイントでコントローラーの処理が走ったか否かも確認しましたが、
>   リクエストは受理されているようでした。

ただ、気になるログがありました。
ブラウザなどでアクセスしたURLは"/contextpath/hello（http://localhost:8080 などで）"となっていますでしょうか？"/contextpath/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.js"になっていませんでしょうか？

Springで"No mapping found for HTTP request"と出力されるとき、その後に表示されるURI（URL）にアクセスしたことととなります。つまり今"/contextpath/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.js"にリクエストがあり、Springが処理したと出力しています。

私自身もomarunさんの掲載したコードで動作させましたところ、Hello World!は表示されました。なので、コードとしては正しいものです（Spring 4.1.1、Tomcat 8.0.17、JDK1.8.0_45）。
そして、私が"/contextpath/index2"と存在しないURLにアクセスすると、今回の現象と同様である以下のログが出力されております。

```
27-Aug-2015 15:54:52.853 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/contextpath/index2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: リクエストURLは正しいものかと思います。
実際は、
http://localhost:8080/contextpath/index
とリクエストしていました。
viewに直接リクエストを飛ばしもしましたが、その際はコントローラーでの処理も動かなかったので、アクセスは正しい方法で行えているものかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

外部の開発環境にリポジトリごと複製し、既存のtomcat8サーバーで起動したところ、Hello World!が表示されました。
その後、質問した際の環境にて再度確認したところ、やはり起動しませんでした。

後者の環境には大した開発環境があるわけでもなかったので、Eclipseを再インストールしたところ、正常な動作を確認しました。
先日から、Windowsより、「Eclipse内部で例外が発生しました」というような内容のエラー通知が何度か来ており、今まで特に支障がなかったため詳細も見ず放置していましたが、
今回それがなんらかの影響を及ぼしていた可能性があります。
はっきりとした原因がわからず申し訳ございません。
ありがとうございました。